# <div (click)="handler()"> does not work in edge, but works in IE11 and other browsers

Tags: css, angular, angular5, microsoft-edge

I have an angular 5.2.8 app. It contains a bit of code:

```
  <div class="login-box">
    <div (click)="toggleMenu()">
      <span class="loginShortTitle">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Login</span>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!menuIsOpen">
      <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
        <input type="text" name="username" ngModel>
        <input type="password" name="password" ngModel>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the component has:

```
public toggleMenu() {
   this.menuIsOpen = !this.menuIsOpen;
}
```

In firefox, chrome and IE 11, clicking the top div will show the login form. However, in Edge 41 it does not. No errors/warnings show in the console...

I thought it might be a CSS issue, when I inspect the elements using the F12 developer tools in edge and change the CSS for the clickable-div; adding "position: relative;" it suddenly DOES become clickable. Even though the developer toolbar shows a strikethrough effect on the position: relative part as if it's being ignored. Removing the property still makes it remain clickable.

The CSS:

```
.login-box {
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  min-width: 12em;
}
.loginShortTitle {
  padding: 1ex 1ex;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: block;
}
```

I'm stumped... does anyone have a clue what's going on ?

--- edit:
I modified my toggleMenu() function to:

```
public toggleMenu() {
   this.menuIsOpen = !this.menuIsOpen;
   window.console.log('clicked toggleMenu');
   window.console.log('Value of this.menuIsOpen=' + (this.menuIsOpen ? 'True' : 'False'));
}
```

and it logs all clicks, even in Edge. The values are as expected. However, nothing happens in the CSS/HTML beyond this point.

---

As per request, the full component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../auth/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public menuIsOpen = false;

  constructor(
    public auth: AuthenticationService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(f) {
    const username = f.value.username;
    const password = f.value.password;

    this.auth.login(username, password).subscribe(
      success => {
        this.closeMenu();
      },
      error => {
      }
    );
  }

  openMenu(): void {
    this.menuIsOpen = true;
  }
  closeMenu(): void {
    this.menuIsOpen = false;
  }
  toggleMenu(): void {
    this.menuIsOpen = !this.menuIsOpen;
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
    this.menuIsOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have something else going on. It's working in this stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btmmjg

Comment: you are correct; the click is being registered. I add a `window.console.log('toggleMenu() triggered');` call to the `toggleMenu` method. But for some odd reason, even though it triggers... nothing further happens... it's as if the callback to angular that the value of the property changed doesn't get sent :|

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was in the `[hidden]="!menuIsOpen"` part. In Edge it would not show the element. Switching it to `*ngIf="menuIsOpen"` dixes the problem.

Comment: Very strange. Can you show us more of the component code, notably the part where `menuIsOpen` is declared (but the whole class would be nice, if not too large). Is `menuIsOpen` present somewhere else in your template?

Comment: I've added the full component in the original question

Comment: Thanks. You don't have something like `#menuIsOpen` somewhere in your template? Just wondering if a template variable declaration might conflict with the class member.

Comment: Another point: you import both `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule`. Do you need `ReactiveFormsModule`? If not, try removing it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Removing it makes no difference. However I just noticed I changed another thing. It wasn't the addition of the this-reference, but the switch from `[hidden]` to `*ngIf` which fixes it. Apparently I hadn't rebuilt in between :$ (updated the answer)

Comment: OK, that makes it less strange. The use of the hidden property is sometimes [discouraged](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/) in Angular 2+.